# Absolute positioning a table

Tags: html, css

Is there some way to use `position: absolute;` with an element that's also `display: table;`?

In the example below I would imagine that the table would be 100% wide and (100% - 50px) high, but it's not. Instead, I'll have to wrap the table in an absolute positioned container and make it 100% wide and high. It feels stupidly redundant. Why doesn't absolute positioning a table work? Is there some way to make it work?

```css
html, body {
    min-height: 90%;
    min-width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
}

body {
    background-color: #333;
}

.table {
    display: table;
    border: 3px solid rebeccapurple;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 33%;
    border: 3px solid #f00;
    
}

.not-a-table {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(0,200,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class="not-a-table">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Confusing name: the .table class and .cell classes should be renamed to something that can't be confused with an HTML element. For your question, you can wrap your element inside a div.

Comment: @frenchie Well, they are a table and two cells if you look at the css. Also, I did mention the div wrapper in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Add width and height in `.table`

```
.table{
   ....
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

Elements with `display:table` property cannot be placed in `absolute` positioning without specifying width and height... Need to use `display:block` property.

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed result in the positioning I was going for, but it doesn't answer the actual question: Why can't I use `position: absolute;` / is there a way to make absolute positioning work?

Comment: I tried `display:block` to the `table`, and `display:table` to the `div`. Now the div loses its width and height. [https://jsfiddle.net/8wxn8sy1/](https://jsfiddle.net/8wxn8sy1/)